# Image of a basis of a free module

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $M$ is a free module with basis $\{m_i|i=1,\dots,s\}$ over a commutative ring $A$ with unity. Suppose $N$ is a submodule. Is it true that the image of a basis of $M$ under the map $M\to M/N$ is a basis if the quotient is free? (I'm particularly interested in the case when $N=\mathscr mM$ where $\mathscr m$ is a maximal ideal of $A$, so let's assume this is the case -- then $M/N$ is a module over $A/\mathscr m$). I find it obvious that the image of any generating set will generate $M/N$, but if there is a relation $(a_1+A)(m_1+N)+\dots(a_s+A)(m_s+N)=0+N$ is $M/N$, why all coeficients $a_i+A$ must be zero? I can take the preimage of the above relation to get $a_1m_1+\dots+a_sm_s\in N$, but I don't see how to use linear independence of $m_1,\dots,m_s$ to conclude that all $a_i+A$ are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to you question is no. If the submodule is nontrivial, it will never be a basis. A nontrivial dependence relation occurs in any expression of a nonzero element of $N$.

Comment: But with $M$ as in question, $M/N\simeq (A/\mathscr m)^n$ is a product of fields, and the image of the standard basis of $M=A^n$ is a basis (also the standard basis). Isn't it true?

Comment: It's a basis over the quotient field, not over the original ring.

Comment: @user In that example, the quotient certainly isn't a free $A$-module.

Comment: I see, I should have stated the question differently. Probably I'll post a new one.

Comment: @user Not sure if you're already aware of this, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma may be relevant.

Comment: I'm not, but in any case, for now I can't see how this is helpful. I've posted a new question.